# How do I use an option from the context menu in a batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to write a simple batch file that will use the 3rd option from a context menu of a .wmv file

I made a hack on my computer to play videos as the back ground but because it is a hack when I restart my computer I have to restart the video by right clicking on it and selecting set as desktop background. I just want to make a simply batch file, and put it in my start up file, that will do this for me but I am having trouble writing the code.

I can't use start *application name* "over.wmv" because I'm not really running an application

Thank you in advance for any and all help.

Comment: so in general you want to start the `wmv` in background? is it really necessary to do this from the context menu?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have your "hack" to play videos, so I can't test this, but I think what that menu option does is something like this :

```
reg.exe add "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /v Wallpaper /t REG_SZ /d "C:\path\over.wmv"
rundll32.exe user32.dll,UpdatePerUserSystemParameters
```